# MS Access - Ambiguous outer joins?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am not sure why my query is netting me the following error:

```
The SQL statement could not be executed because it contains ambiguous outer joins. To force one of the joins to be performed first, create a separate query that performs the firm join and then include that query in your SQL statement.
```

This is my query, I only see one join:

```
SELECT PC.[Mother_Board_Name] & ',' & PC.[Mother_Board_Manufacturer]
FROM PersonalComputerHardware PC, Registers R
WHERE ',' & R.[Names].Value & ',' LIKE '*,' & PC.[Computer_ID] & ',*';
```

R.Names.Value is a reference to a multi-value field, by the way. I don't understand this error message because I am only using one Cross JOIN

Comment: This code makes no sense, it looks like you are trying to build a SQL string in VBA, but are referring to fields as if you are in the query editor?  Can you post up the query as it is actually being run or the rest of the code being used ?

Comment: Hm, this is posted as is from my Query Window. Is it the brackets that looks strange? I can edit those.

Comment: I have never seen a query with this type of construct `',' & R.[Names].Value & ',' `  ? ?  And I've never seen a query use .Value for any field in it's SQL view.

Comment: .Value is the multi-value field in Access. That's how you operate a JOIN on it.

Comment: That syntax is completely off. You better repost either your code or the generated SQL.

Comment: Stay with the Force. Don't get get tempted by the obscure side of multi-value fields. They are a know source of trouble.

Comment: That would explain why I've never seen it. I've never used a multivalued field, as I predominantly use a SQL Sever back end, and they don't work in SQL.  I'd be surprised if a Join works on a multi valued field, but I'm obviously out

Comment: I had an hour playing with multi-value fields a couple of weeks ago before I ran away screaming and used VBA and a listbox to deal with it instead.  Could you show the construct of your tables please - would your actual table hold the value including the comma?  I'm thinking the comma is just used to display the multivalues in the same field, on the (hidden) linked table it's just the values so `R.[Names].Value LIKE '*' & PC.[Computer_ID] & '*'` should work.

Comment: Also - will there be more than one user on the database?  That's when multi-value fields really excel at screwing up your day.  Just thought - how about `FROM PersonalComputerHardware PC INNER JOIN Registers R ON R.Names.Value = PC.[Computer ID]` and removing the `WHERE` clause?.. I know I'm ignoring the `LIKE` but hoping that's only dealing with the commas.

Comment: A multi-valued field is really a separate table that gets joined using an outer join. Access can't handle outer joins and cross joins in one query unless you wrap one of those in a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT PC.Mother_Board_Name & ',' & PC.Mother_Board_Manufacturer
FROM PersonalComputerHardware PC
  INNER JOIN Registers R ON R.Names LIKE '*,' & PC.Computer_ID & ',*'
```

Assuming your actual logic is correct, this should work.

However your logic is probably not correct. At best it will only match `Computer_ID` that is in the middle (not first or last) unless your `Names` has commas at the beginning and end as well.